# How to convert a multidimensional array to a single dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to turn (in PHP) something like

```
(["a"] => (
    ["x"] => "foo",
    ["y"] => "bar"),
["b"] => "moo",
["c"] => (
    ["w"] => (
        ["z"] => "cow" )
        )
)
```

into

```
(["a.x"] => "foo",
["a.y"] => "bar",
["b"] => "moo",
["c.w.z"] => "cow")
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: is it only 3 levels deep or arbitrary levels deep?

Comment: It's arbitrary levels deep, although it rarely goes deeper than 4 levels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a recursive function:

```
function flatten($arr, &$out, $prefix='') {
    $prefix = $prefix ? $prefix . '.' : '';
    foreach($arr as $k => $value) {
        $key =  $prefix . $k;
        if(is_array($value)) {
            flatten($value, $out, $key);
        }
        else {
            $out[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it as

```
$out = array();
flatten($array, $out);
```

Comment: How do I store the full array path as an objects identifier with this one?

Comment: @Cobra: I don't know what you mean. Please elaborate.

Comment: $key = $prefix ? $prefix . '.' . $k : $k;
It actually already store the full array path with this line.
+1 for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You've got something nice here: http://davidwalsh.name/flatten-nested-arrays-php

Comment: On the right track but that by itself won't make keys like OP wants